# Eval function in Dictionary working with individual references but not as dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of variables and values that I assign to them using an eval statement.

I am  trying to use a dictionary comprehension to match the variable with the evaluated value.

When I use a for loop for i in range(0,10) where len(ChosenVarNameList) = 10:

```
 dictinitial = {}
 for i in range (0,len(ChosenVarNameList)):
        dictinitial[ChosenVarNameList[i]] = eval("%s" %ChosenVarNameList[i])
```

I can create the dictionary.

When I reference individual indexes also I can see the dictionary populating correctly (with the code below).

```
      dictinitialnew = {ChosenVarNameList[0] : (eval("%s" 
      %ChosenVarNameList[0])).
```

However when I try a dictionary comprehension like the code below:

```
 dictinitialnew = {ChosenVarNameList[i] : (eval("%s" %ChosenVarNameList[i])) 
 for i in range (0,len(ChosenVarNameList)) }
```

I get code saying the first variable name let's say 'Code1' is not defined. Is there a way to do this using a dictionary comprehension or is there an alternative that I must use to get around this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not entirely clear on why you're using `eval`. It's dangerous at best and seems unnecessary here. Isn't just `ChosenVarNameList[i]` or `str(ChosenVarNameList[i])` identical? Also, please post a working but minimal example. This is likely not enough code to provide an accurate answer. Lastly, Python variable names [should be](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) `snake_case`.

Comment: The thing is the rest of the code is a bit sensitive and that is why i am not putting the rest of it up on line. I will try and see how much more I can put on line. Thanks @ggorlen for helping me though.

Comment: What I can't seem to understand is why does it work in a for loop context and not in a dictionary comprehension context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to `dict` comprehensions introducing nested scope. For most practical purposes, a `dict` comprehension in a function like:

```
def myfunc(iterable, y):
    return {x: y for x in iterable}
```

is implemented as something very similar to:

```
def myfunc(iterable, y):
    def _unnamed_func_(_unnamed_it_):
        retval = {}
        for x in _unnamed_it_:
            retval[x] = y  # Note: y is read from nested scope, not passed to inner func
        return retval
    return _unnamed_func_(iterable)  # Note: iterable passed as argument
```

That `_unnamed_func_`, like all functions with closure scope, determines what values from the nested scope are needed at the moment it is defined and folds them into its own closure scope; in this case, it needs `y` from the nested scope, but not `iterable` (because the first iterable you iterate over is passed to the virtual function as an argument, not through closure scope).

Problem is, `eval` is executed with knowledge of only the local and global scopes (as well as implicit knowledge of the builtin scope that all code has); it doesn't know about the nested scope, and since you only reference the variables via `eval`, the nested function doesn't know it needs them either.

You can demonstrate the general problem with simpler code:

```
def outer(x):
    def inner():
        return eval('x')
    return inner
```

If you try to run that with `outer(1)()` (and no `x` in global scope), it will die with `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`, because `x` was not part of the closure scope of `inner`, and it was promptly discarded when `outer` returned. Changing `eval('x')` to just `x` allows it to work (it returns `1` in the example case), because without `eval` getting in the way, `inner` pulls `x` into its closure scope at definition time so it's available when `inner` is run later.

Your design is a bad one to start with (`eval` should not be used for reading simple variable names), `dict` comprehensions just make it break completely.

The reason is behaves this way is that the language definitions for comprehensions are built off of the definition of a generator expression, and generator expressions *must* be implemented with closure scope; since they run lazily, if they didn't use a closure scope to keep nested variables they rely on alive, by the time they are run out the scope might no longer exist. `list` comprehensions in Python 2 used to execute without a closure, but it caused some weird artifacts (e.g. running `foo = [x for x in y]` in a class definition would give the class a class attribute named `x` with the final value `x` took in the comprehension) and in Python 3, all comprehensions were changed to use an implicit closure scope (this was only a change for listcomps; `dict` and `set` comprehensions were added later, and used closure scopes from the start).

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger will amend my code and take this into account.